# Why I am getting Bad request error for this flask page?

Tags: python, html, forms, flask

I have two flask form in same page. One form is visible at the beginning and user have to select an option and based on that the second form is generated. Second from contains a `dropdown` which will submit the form on `onchange` event. When this submission occurs I am getting bad request error. My Html form is:

```
 <form action="/ip" method="POST" name="btn" value="project">
   <label>Select Project : </label>
   <select class="form-control" style="width: 50%;display:inline-block" name="project_name">
      <option></option>
      <option value="k">Ki</option>
      <option value="s">S</option>
      <option value="l">L</option>
   </select>
   <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary m-b-10 m-l-5" style="display:inline-block" ">Fetch Details</button>
</form>
<form method="POST" action="/ip" name="btn" value="dlvr">
   <select id="subsystem_value" onchange="this.form.submit()">
      {% for i in data %}
      {% for k in i %}
      <option value={{ k }}>{{ k }}</option>
      {% endfor %}
      {% endfor %}
   </select>
</form>
```

and my flask view is :

```
@auth.route('/ip',methods = ['POST', 'GET']) 
def ip():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.form['btn'] == "project":
            project = request.form['project_name']
            c, conn = connection()
            subsystem = "SELECT distinct sub from ip where project='{}'".format(project)
            query = "SELECT distinct del from ip where project='{}'".format(project)
            c.execute(query)
            data = c.fetchall()
            c.execute(subsystem)
            subsystem = c.fetchall()
            sub = []
            for row in subsystem:
                for id in row:
                    sub.append(id)
            conn.close() 
            return render_template('ip.html', data=data,sub=sub)
        else:
          subsystem = request.form['subsystem_value']  
          return render_template('ip.html')     
    else:
        return render_template('ip.html')
```

I tried to make same name for forms and gave separate values too. But still I am getting bad request error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have two areas where your error is coming from

1) Form name is deprecated since HTML 4 and is no longer submitted therefore

```
if request.form['btn'] == "project":
```

will not be understood by flask

The way to go around that is to give your submit button a name like this

```
<button type="submit" name="project" class="btn btn-primary m-b-10 m-l-5" style="display:inline-block" ">Fetch Details</button>
```

and in your flask view, check for the form like this

```
if 'project' in request.form:
```

2) The second error is on this line

```
<form method="POST" action="/ip" name="btn" value="dlvr">
   <select id="subsystem_value" onchange="this.form.submit()">
```

line two here should be `name= "subsystem_value"`, not `id="subsystem_value"`
otherwise this line in flask will not be understood

```
subsystem = request.form['subsystem_value']
```

So I have this simplified code that is no longer giving me an error and returning the values the way I think you want them

in flask

```
@app.route('/ip',methods = ['POST', 'GET']) #Used @pp.route to match my testing app
def ip():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'project' in request.form:
            project = request.form['project_name']

            return str(project)
        else:
          subsystem = request.form['subsystem_value']  
          return str(subsystem)     
    else:
        return render_template('test.html')
```

in the template

```
<form action="/ip" method="POST"  >
   <label>Select Project : </label>
   <select class="form-control" style="width: 50%;display:inline-block" name="project_name">
      <option></option>
      <option value="k">Ki</option>
      <option value="s">S</option>
      <option value="l">L</option>
   </select>
   <button type="submit" name="project" class="btn btn-primary m-b-10 m-l-5" style="display:inline-block" ">Fetch Details</button>
</form>
<form name method="POST" action="/ip" >
   <select name="subsystem_value" onchange="this.form.submit();">
      <option value="test1">t1</option>
      <option value="test2">t2</option>
      <option value="test3">t3</option>

   </select>
</form>
```

Hope that helps you out

Comment: No i am getting error.. now i cant submit form 1...it gives bad request

Comment: On the simplified code above, am able to submit both. May be you can start from the code in the answer, then slowly add your code to see where the error is

Answer (score 0):

You are in the perfect position to avail yourself of Flasks debug facilities, which you can activate by either setting the environment variable `FLASK_DEBUG=1` or by passing `debug=True` to `app.run()`.

See http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Flask.debug

Also, if there's any chance that this code will face hostile users, use SQL bind variables instead of constructing a query from untrusted input. A SQL Injection attack can ruin your day.

Comment: And neither it nor the logs are giving you any useful info? BTW, I assume you're using a Blueprint. Otherwise, you'd want `@app.route` instead of `@auth.route`.